# Changing element which is my element instead of direct my element

Tags: javascript, css

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".night").forEach((e) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let settingsBox = document.querySelector(".settings_box");
            if(settingsBox.style.display === "none") {
                settingsBox.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                settingsBox.style.display = "none";
            }
        })
    });
});
```

After the page is loaded:

`.settings_box` is set to `display: none`

When I click on `.night` element, the browser strikes `display: none` in `.settings_box` and gives `display: none` to `element` which is probably `.settings_box`. When I click again, it sets `display: none` to `block` in `element`.

Comment: This code seems ok, give more code so we can check [repro]

Comment: html code please

Comment: Why are you using await for a non-async function?

Comment: You are only telling what IS happening. Now you need to tell us what you WANT to happen. Again, give full(er) code so we can reproduce (HTML, CSS and JS).......

Answer (score 0):

By using `document.querySelector(".settings_box")` you are getting the first element that matches provided selector in this case `.settings_box` after that you are operating on that element instance not on styles for that particular selector.

To actualy modify styles for some selector you would have to create stylesheet with that selector but probably you dont want to do that.

Alternative solution for hiding somethin with styles is creating something like this:

```
// in stylesheet
.hide-boxes .settings_box {
  display: none;
}
```

then in dom you add `hide-boxes` class to ancestor element and all boxes disappear and when you drop it the appear again.

Comment: Why does it refer to some instance and does not to direct element? Does exist some better way?

Comment: @J.Doe instance means some specific element in DOM tree at this point you need to better explain what you expect to be answered do you ask why style changes for that specific instance or why it gets display none on element instead of reverting to using stylesheet styles?